# showing data in individual tabs, passing dropdown list value to the tab selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on angular and bootstrap application.
Please find the demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CfTrnfCAt09eDtLGDW6P?p=preview)

I have the below two requirements:

- I have a dropdown list, by default option1 is selected, i want to
  pass the id of the option selected to the tab controller(tabsctrl).
- When user click on Tab1, tab1 data should be viewed and when user
  click on Tab2, tab2 data should be viewed.

js code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('tabs', [ 'ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.controller('tabsctrl', function ($rootScope,$scope) {
          $rootScope.tabName ='MyTab Name';
          $rootScope.selectedDropDownValue="dummy";
          alert("selected dropdown value : " + $rootScope.selectedDropDownValue);
    $rootScope.tabValue="tab1Value";
    $scope.applicationData = {};
    $scope.activeModule = "Tab1";
    $scope.programModules=[{"tabName":"Tab1","tabValue":"tab1Value"},{"tabName":"Tab2","tabValue":"tab2Value"}];
    $scope.loadApplicationData = function(tabVal,tabName){
        $rootScope.tabName =tabName;
     alert("$rootScope.tabName :: "+$rootScope.tabName);
        $rootScope.tabValue=tabVal;
        $scope.activeModule = tabVal;

    }; 
    $scope.loadApplicationData($scope.activeModule,'Tab1');
});

myApp.controller('dropDownListCtrl',function Ctrl($rootScope,$scope) {  
    $scope.list_categories = {
        data: [{
            id: 'id1',
            name: 'option1'
        }, {
            id: 'id2',
            name: 'option2'
        }]
    };       
    $scope.list_category = 'id1';
});
```

html code:

```
<div ng-controller="dropDownListCtrl">
    <select id="sel" class="input-block-level" ng-model="list_category" ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in list_categories.data">    

    </select>

    <p>$scope.list_category: {{list_category}}<p>

</div>
  <br><br>
<div ng-controller="tabsctrl">
 <div class="top-tabs">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
            <li role="presentation" class="{{ pg.tabValue == activeModule? 'active':''}}" ng-repeat="pg in programModules">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"  ng-click="loadApplicationData(pg.tabValue,pg.tabName)" >{{pg.tabName}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

         <div class="tab-content">

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 Tab1 data
                            </div>asdsa
                            </div>
                            </div><div></div>
              <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                 Tab2 data
                            </div>asdsa
                            </div>
                            </div><div></div>  </div>
                            </div>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Unless you the project requires you to reinvent the wheel, use a library like `ui-bootstrap` https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: @TheHeadRush - no, i dont want to reinvent. I'm almost there.Please see  the link http://plnkr.co/edit/CfTrnfCAt09eDtLGDW6P?p=preview .